# ADO YAML failing: No repository found by name templates

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm trying to edit an ADO YAML file down to the bare minimum in order to isolate another issue.

When I run Validate, it comes back with the following error:

`No repository found by name templates`

Here's the general gist of my YAML:

```
#resources:
#  repositories:
#    - repository: templates
#      type: git
#      name: TemplateProject/TemplateRepo

name: $(VersionName)
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main
  batch: true
  paths:
    exclude: $(ListOfExclusions)
stages:
  - template: core/setVersion.yml@templates
  - stage: Build
    pool: linux
    jobs:
      - job: BuildDocker
        displayName: Build and Push Docker Image
        pool: linux
        steps:
          - task: Docker@2
            displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
            inputs:
              command: buildAndPush
              repository: $(RepoName)
              dockerfile: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Dockerfile
              containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
              tags: |
                $(Tag)
```

What could be going wrong? The error message makes me think the YAML isn't clean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I caused a simple typo when commenting out the `resources` section of the YAML. I had a `template` part of the stage that also needed to be commented out, and I neglected to do this.

Once I updated the code to read:

```
stages:
#  - template: core/setVersion.yml@templates
  - stage: Build
    pool: linux
    jobs:
      - job: BuildDocker
      # etc...
```

Now my YAML validates with `OK`.

Comment: How did you validate the yaml?

Comment: @WestCoastProjects In ADO, when you are editing the pipeline in the "Pipelines" view (the one that gives you autocomplete, not just editing the YML file directly in "Repos"), hit the "kebab" menu (next to the "Variables" and "Run" buttons). In this menu, there's an option to Validate. Sometimes it gives you cryptic output (as above), but it sure beats trying to actually run the pipeline and seeing an error. Hope this helps!